# Excel Vba Exit sub function issue

Tags: excel, vba

I can't deal with making "Exit Sub" function work the way I need. The goal of macro I'm working on  is to import data from another workbook to temporary sheet, do some basic formatting and then copy these data to first empty row in a target sheet.
To avoid duplicating records in the target sheet i need to compare it with the temporary one and exit sub if there are no new records - the compared criteria are dates ('3). It works properly only when there are fresh data, they are copied to the target worsheet excactly the way I want.
On the other hand when there are no fresh records the macro copies the header from the temporary sheet to the target one (to 1st empty row) instead of exit the sub as intended. I use the following code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Fnm As String ' 1. Import raw data from another workbook to temporary sheet
Dim SrcWb As Workbook
Dim DestWb As Workbook
Set DestWb = ThisWorkbook

Fnm = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If Fnm = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open(Fnm)
SrcWb.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("A:CJ").Copy DestWb.Sheets("Tmp_Data").Range("A:CJ")
SrcWb.Close False

If Arkusz2 Is ActiveSheet Then ' 2. Necessary formatting of temporary sheet
    Call CleanData
Else
    Arkusz2.Activate
    Call CleanData
End If

Dim Max_date1, Max_date2 As Date ' 3. Compare dates in temporary and target sheet - not working when no fresh records
Max_date1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Arkusz2.Columns("E:E"))
Max_date2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Arkusz3.Columns("E:E"))

If Max_date1 <= Max_date2 Then
    MsgBox "No new data to copy"
    Call DlTmpData

    Exit Sub
End If

Call ClFltr ' 4. Filter data in temporary sheet
Call CopyTmpData ' 5. Copy filtered data from temporary to target sheet

If Arkusz3 Is ActiveSheet Then ' 6. Formatting data in target sheet
    Call ClFrmt
Else
    Arkusz3.Activate
    Call ClFrmt
End If

Call DlTmpData ' 7. Remove data from temporary sheet
```

Comment: Put a break on the line `If Max_date1 <= Max_date2 Then` and make sure the dates are what you expect from the data.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the answer, but it did not help. In fact when I use this part ('3) of original code in an independent macro (of course with no"Exit sub" funtion in this case) it works (MsgBox pops up, the other macro is initiated - what makes me suppose that the data are ok), but as a part of the original code these three lines (with MsgBox, Call DlTmpData, Exit Sub) seem to be skipped and the original code runs to the end instead of being stopped.

Comment: Put the break in your actual code - if code does not stop in that line then something else is going on which we don't have visibility on.